# Making a bar chart in Jaspersoft studio 508 compliant

Tags: jasper-reports, screen-readers, section508

I have a pdf report created within Jaspersoft studio and the biggest issue I am having is making it both 508 accessible via screen readers and colors of each series.

I've been told I need to make the bars have different patterns for each series but I am not sure how to do that in Jasper, all I have been seeing is a way to change the solid color of each bar.

Then I know there are tags for tables in jasper to make it readable to a screen reader, is there something similar for charts or is alt-text the only way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessible graphs for screen reader users is a huge challenge.  Making a graph readable for a color deficient user is a bit easier.  As you mentioned, patterns are typically used (although I'm not familiar with jasper so I can't comment on how to implement patterns, sorry).  If you have a color graph, try viewing it in gray scale to see how the contrast between data series looks (print on a black and white printer).  That's typically why you'd want patterns.

One of the new WCAG 2.1 guidelines talks about how adjacent graphical elements (such as two bars next to each other) should have a minimum contrast ratio of 3:1.  See success criteria [2.4.1 - Non-text Contrast](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/non-text-contrast.html).  So if you had a light blue bar and a dark blue bar, it might be ok, although patterns are the best bet.

(If you have the rgb values for the colors of your bars, you can use a color contrast checker such as https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/ to see if you have a sufficient 3:1 ratio)

I'm not aware of a way to make a graph accessible in pdf.  If you had an alt attribute, it would have to be very lengthy to accurately describe the graph.